# PHP Couchbase setMulti weird output

Tags: php, couchbase

I have the following code:

```
$objDriver = new Couchbase($strHostname . ':' . $strPort, $strUsername, $strPassword, $strDataBucket, $blnPersistent);

$arrDocs = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'document' => json_encode(array(
            'test' => 'test',
            'x' => 'y'
        ))
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'document' => json_encode(array(
            'test1' => 'test1',
            'y' => 'x'
        ))
    )
);

var_dump($objDriver->setMulti($arrDocs, 360));
var_dump($objDriver->get(1));
var_dump($objDriver->get(2));
```

The output for that code is:

```
array(2) {
  ["1"]=>
  string(19) "2871475064714901504"
  ["0"]=>
  string(19) "5562107574183606272"
}
array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(2)
  ["document"]=>
  string(25) "{"test1":"test1","y":"x"}"
}
bool(false)
```

It seems that I can only get the second document, which is really odd.
The documentation on setMulti ( http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-php-client-1.1.5/classes/Couchbase.html#method_setMulti ): `setMulti(array $documents, integer $expiry, integer $persist_to, integer $replicate_to) : boolean` states that documents must be in a form of array(id, document) pairs, so my code seems correct.

And as you can see, the documentation on setMulti states that the function returns a boolean, but here it returns an array.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$cb_data = array(
array($id => $document),
array($id1 => $document1),
...
)
```

`$id` is a key of Couchbase data.

`$document` is json data